# .NET Core use Configuration to bind to Options with Array

Tags: c#, configuration, asp.net-core, .net-core

Using the .NET Core `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` **is it possible to bind to a Configuration to an object that contains an array?**

`ConfigurationBinder` has a method [BindArray](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder/ConfigurationBinder.cs#L273-L305), so I'd assume it would work.

But when I try it out I get an exception:

> `System.NotSupportedException: ArrayConverter cannot convert from System.String.`

Here's my slimmed down code:

```
public class Test
{
   private class ExampleOption
   { 
      public int[] Array {get;set;}
   }

   [Test]
   public void CanBindArray()
   {
       // ARRANGE
       var config =
            new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddInMemoryCollection(new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Array", "[1,2,3]")
            })
            .Build();

        var exampleOption= new ExampleOption();

        // ACT
        config.Bind(complexOptions); // throws exception

       // ASSERT
       exampleOption.ShouldContain(1);
   }
}
```

Comment: The sample property "Array" is a little bit tricky for explanations ;) I would have corrected it but there was already another answer and a comment which I could not correct.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The error is in your input definition. The sample sets a key "Array" to a string value of "[1,2,3]" (in the C# based InMemoryCollection) and makes the assumption it is parsed JSON style. That is wrong. It is just not parsed.

The encoding convention of array values in the config system is by repeating the key with a colon and an index behind it. The following sample works like you intend to do:

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddInMemoryCollection(new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Array:0", "1"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Array:1", "2"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Array:2", "3")
        })
        .Build();
```

The colon-key-repeating scheme happens also if JSON file is used (here by an additional call to AddJsonFile) ...

```
{
  "mySecondArray":  [1, 2, 3]
}
```

the resulting combined configuration will contain the keys which follow the same pattern as illustrated for in-memory usage above:

```
Count = 8
[0]: {[mySecondArray, ]}
[1]: {[mySecondArray:2, 3]}
[2]: {[mySecondArray:1, 2]}
[3]: {[mySecondArray:0, 1]}
[4]: {[Array, ]}
[5]: {[Array:2, 3]}
[6]: {[Array:1, 2]}
[7]: {[Array:0, 1]}
```

The config system is agnostic to storage formats like JSON/INI/XML/... and is essentially just a string->string dictionary with colon making up a hierarchy **within the key**.

Bind is then able to interpret some of the hierarchy by **conventions** and therefore binds also arrays, collections, objects and dictionaries. Interestingly for arrays, it does not care about the numbers behind the colon but just [iterate](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder/ConfigurationBinder.cs#L286) the children of the configuration section (here "Array") and take the values of the children. The [sorting](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration/ConfigurationKeyComparer.cs) of the children again, takes the numbers into consideration but also sorts strings as a second option (OrdinalIgnoreCase).

Comment: The config system of ASP.NET is really a nice and useful piece of technology also outside of ASP.NET. Should be in everyone's toolbox.

Comment: Here Here!  Quick tangent: Have you seen any documentation/blogs on how to wire up `IOptions` using 3rd party DI?  I built a prototype using Ninject, but not sure I've got full support for everything, especially `ChangeToken`s.

Comment: No Idea. I am weak on the options topic.

Comment: You can use the same technique for non-value types as well, you just need to append the property to the key. So if your class contained Id and Name, you'd have two key entries: "Array:0:Id" and "Array:0:Name". (Learned after struggling with using a JSON string as a value and getting null returned).

Answer (score 17):

With recent additions to C# language it is cleaner to use the newer syntax:

```cs
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddInMemoryCollection(new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "Array:0", "1" },
        { "Array:1", "2" },
        { "Array:2", "3" },
    })
    .Build();
```

or you can use other new syntax

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddInMemoryCollection(new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        ["Array:0"] = "1",
        ["Array:1"] = "2",
        ["Array:2"] = "3",
    })
    .Build();
```

Comment: With the additions it should look like this: `["Array:0"] = "1", ...`.

Answer (score 7):

You can configure `ExampleOption`with code in `ConfigureServices` method:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
      services.Configure<ExampleOption>(myOptions =>
      {
          myOptions.Array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
      });
 }
```

or if you want to use json configuration file

`appsettings.json`:

```
{
  "ExampleOption": {
     "Array": [1,2,3]
  }
}
```

`ConfigureServices`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<ExampleOption>(Configuration.GetSection("ExampleOption"));
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this without the Options Extensions?  Using only `ConfigurationBinder`?  And when I use `"Array":"[1,2,3]"` in the In Memory Configuration, that's when I get the ArraryConverter exception I cited.  Are you saying it works in a Json file?

Comment: i don't know if there is a way to solve without Options Extensions but in a json file it works as expected.

Comment: Thanks for answering here.  It's good to know that the array initialization syntax is nice and simple for Json files; but doesn't fully align with what I was looking for in this question (using `AddInMemoryCollection`)

Answer (score 0):

here is a simpler approach where you can do it without necessarily re-initializing configuration. this approach also avoids the messy "options pattern".

```
#region SET DEMO STATE
var demoMode = true; // switch this and rebuild to change demo state
var inMemorySettings = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string?>>
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string?>("DemoMode", demoMode.ToString())
    };
builder.Configuration.AddInMemoryCollection(inMemorySettings);
// HOW TO USE: `configuration["DemoMode"]`
#endregion
```

Just like that, you can add/inject properties into existing configuration with code. You can even do it in a single line, but it would be less readable. You can then use dependency injection as usual and access this property with `configuration["DemoMode"]`, as if it was a property in `appsettings.json`.

Note: This is useful if you don't want to expose some settings to `appsettings.json`.

Comment: the "Messy Options Pattern" facilitates strong typing of configuration, which is what I was looking to use.

Your solution looks to use a `Dictionary<string,string>`.  While the binding is simpler, it uses magic string (for keys) and stores all config values as strings - both of which I am looking to avoid.