# Mock IConfigurationSection to return array of string

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, configuration, moq

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50201588/c-sharp-how-to-mock-configuration-getsectionfoobar-getliststring) answer to mock the `IConfiguration` methods from an ASP.NET Core app.

I need to mock an `IConfigurationSection` to return a `string` array.

My configuration class looks like this:

```cs
public class LoggingConfiguration
{
    public string ApplicationName { get; set; }
    public string[] Loggers { get; set; }
}
```

appsettings.json

```json
{
    "Logging": {
        "LoggingConfiguration": {
              "ApplicationName": "Some app",
              "Loggers":  [ "DiskLogger", "MemoryLogger"],
              "DiskLogger": {
                  "SomeSettingOne" : "setting",
                  "SomeSettingTwo" : "setting",
               },
              "MemoryLogger": {
                  "AnotherSetting": "...",
               }
       }
}
```

In setting up the mocks - I have two problems.

1. I can't figure out how to mock an `IConfigurationSection` that would return `string[]` (`loggers`)
2. I am getting an exception when I try to setup the `GetChildren()` method on the `LoggingSectionMock`

```cs
public void Setup()
{
    var applicationNameConfigurationSectionMock = new Mock<IConfigurationSection>();
    applicationNameConfigurationSectionMock.Setup(m => m.Value).Returns(TestingApplicationName);

    var loggerNamesConfigurationSectionMock = new Mock<IConfigurationSection>();
    loggerNamesConfigurationSectionMock.Setup(m => m.GetChildren()).Returns(GetLoggerNamesSection);

    //Throwing Method Not Found exception
    LoggingSectionMock.Setup(m => m.GetChildren()).Returns(new List<IConfigurationSection>
        {applicationNameConfigurationSectionMock.Object, loggerNamesConfigurationSectionMock.Object});

    ConfigurationMock.Setup(m => m.GetSection($"{Logging}:{LoggingConfiguration}"))
        .Returns(() => LoggingSectionMock.Object);
}

private IEnumerable<IConfigurationSection> GetLoggerNamesSection()
{
    var loggerNamesConfigurationSections = new List<IConfigurationSection>();
    LoggerNames.ToList().ForEach(loggerName =>
    {
        var configSectionMock = new Mock<IConfigurationSection>();
        configSectionMock.Setup(m => m.Value).Returns(loggerName);
        loggerNamesConfigurationSections.Add(configSectionMock.Object);
    });
    return loggerNamesConfigurationSections;
}
```

Comment: Build an actual IConfiguration using in memory data. Way too much effort to try and mock all that.

Comment: Show what you are **actually** trying to test. This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As an alternative you can take advantage of `ConfigurationBuilder`'s `AddInMemoryCollection`:

Reference [Memory configuration provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#memory-configuration-provider)

#### Setup

```cs
IConfiguration configRoot = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddInMemoryCollection(new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "ApplicationName", "App" }, 
        { "Loggers:0", "1" },
        { "Loggers:1", "2" },
        { "Loggers:2", "3" }
    })
    .Build();
```

#### Usage

```cs
LoggingConfiguration config = configRoot.Get<LoggingConfiguration>();
```

Comment: Yep. This is exactly what I was referring to. Good answer.

Comment: I like this approach - but my appsettings.json is more complicated.  I have updated my question to show the appsettings.json structure.  I Need to get the "LoggingConfiguration" section of the file.

Comment: I think I found it.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37825107/net-core-use-configuration-to-bind-to-options-with-array.